# Creating an Output vs. snipping tool

Tags: qgis

I´m very new to QGIS and I would just look to have a "screenshot" of a map that I created.

When using snipping tool I get images of rather bad quality and when I use the "create ouput" tool my image is very large and it seems that this tool is mostly used to add other elements to the maps.

How do I get simple "screenshots" of a maps in decent quality?

Answer (score 8):

You can save the currently displayed view as .jpg file using:

Project --> Save as Image

Alternativly you could take a look at the Print Composer that will enable you to export complete maps containing a proper frame, scale, legend and to define the (data)size and format of your output.